# unable to install pylibmc on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, libmemcached, pylibmc

I am trying to install pylibmc using "pip install pylibmc" on my windows 10 machine but I am getting the following error. I need to know if there is any way to install libmemcached on windows 10 as I need to install pylibmc which requires libmemcached.

> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DUSE_ZLIB -Ic:\anaconda\include
>   -Ic:\anaconda\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_pylibmcmodule.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_pylibmcmodule.obj
>   -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c99 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fno-strict-aliasing' cl : Command line
>   warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99' _pylibmcmodule.c
>   c:\users\yashpal
>   singh\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ag730kcd\pylibmc\src_pylibmcmodule.h(42):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'libmemcached/memcached.h': No such file or directory error: command
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2

---

> Command "c:\anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;file='C:\Users\YASHPA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ag730kcd\pylibmc\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record
>   C:\Users\YASHPA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u9a31aiv\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\YASHPA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ag730kcd\pylibmc\