# Installing Python pylibmc on Windows fails with "Cannot open include file: 'libmemcached/memcached.h'"

Tags: python, pip, memcached, libmemcached, pylibmc

I apparently need memcached to use pylibmc with Django but it keeps popping

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
> 'libmemcached/memcached.h': No such file or directory

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846281/unable-to-install-pylibmc-on-windows) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779705/not-able-to-install-python-libmemcached-on-windows) for Windows (among others) which don't have working answers, plus [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934082/pylibmc-installation-error-using-pip-in-python) that seems to be the widely accepted answer, but on Linux..

I even tried downloading the memcached source and adding the files to my include folder directly but it always pops new errors. I can't believe I'm the only one using Django on Windows, needing pylibmc. Anyone has the answer to that issue?

Comment: Try installing `libmemcached-win` using the zip https://github.com/yshurik/libmemcached-win/releases/tag/1.0.18

Comment: Thanks friend, your comment got me pas this issue, however it's looking for more libs after, and it seems pylibmc is not supported on Windows. So unless someone else has a solution, it doesn't look like this can be done

Comment: Yeah libmemcached is not having a proper binary for windows, i will try to setup in my windows machine today and will let you if i can clear the hurdles.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seem like pylibmc is [not supported on Windows](https://github.com/lericson/pylibmc/issues/247#issuecomment-542181398). So it's possible this cannot be fixed.